# Integrating php in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

This is jquery ajax method success message in which php code is integrated. If i am integrating php inside jquery . Below is the error in which i am getting. I am new to jquery not able to expect what is the error.

- Uncaught ReferenceError: save_customer is not defined
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Here is the code:

```
function save_customer() {
  $('#save_customer_loader').show();
  // temporarily enable the billing fields (if disabled)
  /*if($('#different_address').is(':checked'))
     {
     $('.bill').attr('disabled', false);
     $('.bill').removeClass('disabled');
     }*/
  //send data to server
  form_data = $('#customer_info_form').serialize();

  $.post('<?php echo site_url('checkout / save_customer ') ?>', form_data, function(response) {
      if (typeof response != "object") // error
      {
        display_error('customer', '<?php echo lang('communication_error ');?>');
        return;
      }

      if (response.status == 'success') {

        <? php
        foreach($this - > go_cart - > contents() as $contents) {
          // check whether product polls are there and user has given poll feedback

          $result_row = $this - > db - > get_where('tryproduct_questionnaires', array('id' = > $contents['id'])) - > row();
          if ($result_row > 0) { ?>

            window.location = "<?php echo base_url();?>cart/tryproduct_questionnaires/<?php echo
 $contents['id'];?>"; <? php
          }
        } ?>
        //populate the information from ajax, so someone cannot use developer tools to edit the form after it's saved
        $('#customer_info_fields').html(response.view);
        // and update the summary to show proper tax information / discounts
        update_summary();
      } else if (response.status == 'error') {
        display_error('customer', response.error);
        $('#save_customer_loader').hide();
      }
    }, 'json');
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get these errors?  Can you perhaps format the code to be human-readable?

Comment: $result_row=$this->db->get_where('tryproduct_questionnaires',array('id'=>$contents['id']))->row();
if($result_row>0)
{   ?>  here i am getting error

Comment: from this line -->$result_row

Comment: It seems you're getting the ReferenceError because you haven't defined save_customer, but you're asking PHP to calculate `checkout / save_customer`?

Comment: no it is defined i updated the code

Comment: <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button" value="Continue" onclick="save_customer()"/>

Comment: @MjrKusanagi checkout/save_customer looks more like a URL path to me

Comment: By writing code like this you are creating what is known as `escaping hell`. This is not a recommended way to write code as it is extremely difficult to maintain and as you can see early on, you are having issues with silly things already. Please save yourself and everyone that comes after you the headaches and do **NOT** continue on this path.

Comment: Does this file even have a `.php` file extension?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you should write it like this:

```
$result_row = $this - > db - > get_where('tryproduct_questionnaires', array('id' = > $contents['id'])) - > row();
   if ($result_row > 0) {
       echo "window.location = '".base_url()."cart/tryproduct_questionnaires/". $contents['id']."';";
   }
```

In general, you have to keep in mind, that your server sends generated javascript code. Your code becomes easier to read if you stay in the  mode and make use of echo 'your js code';

Furthermore, you can't call it integration of PHP into jQuery. It doesn't make any sense, since PHP is executed on the server and jQuery is run by the client (browser). All you can do is generating javascript/jQuery code by PHP and send it to the client for execution. But your basis is PHP, not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax error, I would try separating that line of code:

```
$result_where = $this - > db - > get_where('tryproduct_questionnaires', array('id' = > $contents['id']));
$result_row = ($result_where ? $result_where - > row() : false);
```

That way you're verifying that the object exists before attempting to call it's row function.